# cabal install cabal-install could not resolve dependencies

Tags: haskell, osx-mavericks, homebrew, cabal, haskell-platform

I just did `brew install haskell-platform` and it installed *The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.6.3* .

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.16.0.2
using version 1.16.0 of the Cabal library

$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

$ cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: cabal-install-1.20.0.3
rejecting: zlib-0.5.4.1, 0.5.4.0, 0.5.3.3, 0.5.3.2, 0.5.3.1, 0.5.2.0, 0.5.0.0,
0.4.0.4, 0.4.0.3, 0.4.0.2, 0.4.0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2 (global constraint requires 
installed instance)
```

I don't understand what the problem is here, I just installed everything for the first time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just had a bad `~/.cabal/config` file before installing.

I did

```
$ rm -rf ~/.ghc ~/.cabal
$ brew rm ghc 
$ brew rm haskell-platform
$ brew install haskell-platform
```

and it installed OK

```
$ cabal install cabal-install
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading Cabal-1.20.0.2...
...
```